# "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error when importing react-hook-mousetrap in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, es6-modules

Trying out Next.js but I'm struggling with the following. Just tried to install `react-hook-mousetrap` and imported it like I normally would:

```
import useMousetrap from "react-hook-mousetrap";
```

This gives me the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
1 > module.exports = require("react-hook-mousetrap");
```

I am not sure what this means? I then thought it might be a problem with Nextjs's SSR, since my library enables hotkeys and will use some browser APIs. If you already know that I am on the wrong track here you can stop reading now.

What I did next however was this, I tried dynamic imports:

**1. Dynamic import with next/dynamic**

First thing I came across was `next/dynamic`, but this seems to be for JSX / React Components only (correct me if I'm wrong). Here I will be importing and using a **React hook**.

**2. Dynamic import with await (...).default**

So I tried [dynamically importing it as a module](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import), but I'm not sure how to do this exactly.

I need to use my hook at the top level of my component, can't make that Component async and now don't know what to do?

```
const MyComponent = () => {  
    
 // (1) TRIED THIS:
 const useMousetrap = await import("react-hook-mousetrap").default;
 //can't use the hook here since my Component is not async; Can't make the Component async, since this breaks stuff
 
 // (2) TRIED THIS:
    (async () => {
 const useMousetrap = (await import("react-hook-mousetrap")).default;
 // in this async function i can't use the hook, because it needs to be called at the top level.

    })()

 //....
}
```

Any advice here would be appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer. It really helped me out!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The error occurs because `react-hook-mousetrap` is exported as an ESM library.

#### Before Next.js 13.1

You can have Next.js transpile it using [`next-transpile-modules`](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules) in your `next.config.js`.

```js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['react-hook-mousetrap']);

module.exports = withTM({ /* Your Next.js config */});
```

---

#### From Next.js 13.1

From Next.js 13.1, transpilation is natively supported, using `next-transpile-modules` is no longer needed.

```js
module.exports = {
    transpilePackages: ['react-hook-mousetrap'],
    /* Your Next.js config */
};
```

Comment: as a library maintainer is there a way to make it so out users don't need to do this step?

Comment: @Daniel From Next.js 12, as long as your ESM library has `"type": "module"` in its `package.json` you can import it in a Next.js project without using `next-transpile-modules`. See https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11-1#es-modules-support.

Comment: Hey @juliomalves could there be any reason that I'm still getting this error, even though I've changed the "type" to "module" in my package.json ?

Comment: @TochiBedford Is that the Next.js `package.json`, or the external library you're trying to consume `package.json`?

Comment: @juliomalves the external library. I am actually the maintainer of said external library and the package.json type is set to "module" so I'm not sure why I still get the error

Comment: This is deprecated https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules/releases/tag/the-end the link has how to use transpiling in next.js immediately

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if my answer is actual, but i'm facing whith this problem today, and what that i done:

```
//test component for modal 
const Button: React.FC<{close?: () => void}> = ({ close }) => (
 <React.Fragment>
    <button type="button" onClick={ close }>Close</button>
 </React.Fragment>
);

// async call import react custom hook in next js whithout a dynamic 
//import
let newHook;

(async () => {
 const { hookFromNodeModules } = 
 await import('path/to/hook');

 newHook = hookFromNodeModules;
})();

export default function Home() {
// check if hook is available
const openModal = newHook && newHook();

const { t } = useTranslation('common');

// useCallback for update call function when hook is available
const handleOpen = React.useCallback(() => {
    openModal?.openModal(Button, {});
}, [openModal]);

 return ( ...your code )
}
```

hope this help!)

[screen from next.js app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxSTD.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you come across errors such as "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'" or "'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'", along with similar issues, it's necessary to include the module causing the problem in the transpilePackages configuration.

**next.config.mjs or next.config.js**

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  transpilePackages: [
    "antd",
    "rc-util",
    "@babel/runtime",
    "@ant-design/icons",
    "@ant-design/icons-svg",
    "rc-pagination",
    "rc-picker",
    "rc-tree",
    "rc-table",
  ],
};

export default nextConfig;
```