# Getting SyntaxError when using lightweight-charts in NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, lightweight-charts

I'm trying to use the `lightweight-charts` package in my `nextjs` project, however when i try to call the `createChart` function I get this error in my nodejs console.

```
...\lightweight-charts\dist\lightweight-charts.esm.development.js:7
import { bindToDevicePixelRatio } from 'fancy-canvas/coordinate-space';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Component:

```
import styled from "styled-components"
import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts';

const Wrapper = styled.div``

const CoinPriceChart = () => {
  const chart = createChart(document.body, { width: 400, height: 300 });
  return <Wrapper></Wrapper>
}

export default CoinPriceChart
```

Page:

```
import styled from "styled-components"
import CoinPriceChart from "../../components/charts/CoinPriceChart"

const Wrapper = styled.div``

const CoinDetailPage = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <CoinPriceChart />
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

export default CoinDetailPage
```

**Does someone have an idea what I could do to enable me to use the library within nextjs?**
Thank you!

Comment: Does this help answer your question [NextJS + react-hook-mousetrap : “Cannot use import statement outside a module”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66246141/1870780)? Different lib but same solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That because you are trying to import the library in SSR context.
Using next.js `Dynamic` with `ssr : false` should fix the issue :

```
import styled from "styled-components"
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const CoinPriceChart = dynamic(() => import("../../components/charts/CoinPriceChart"), {
  ssr: false
});

const Wrapper = styled.div``

const CoinDetailPage = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <CoinPriceChart />
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

export default CoinDetailPage
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you very much Nico!

Comment: Nice is correct. I just wanna add a comment that if you need to import some others from "../../components/charts/CoinPriceChart" and they are not components, put them in a separate file. In my case, they are constants and types

Comment: I get an error when doing suspense:true. Does someone has a solution for that?