# Next.js seemingly erroneous message "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: webpack, import, three.js, next.js

**Scenario**

I'm working on a group project and one of the project maintainers understandably wants to use Next.js. We are using three.js in the project and while leveraging the GLTFLoader I've run into something unsuspected.

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Which seems due to importing the `GLTFLoader` like so

```
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
```

I KIND OF understand why this would happen but check this out: if I comment out the `import` line and refresh the browser then I see a page with no errors as expected. Now the page is hot-reloading and if I uncomment the `GLTFLoader` import along with the `GLTFLoader` code then everything works as expected!

BUT

If I refresh the page manually I'm greeted with the initial `SyntaxError` message & description and have to comment out & uncomment code accordingly.

**Question**

Why is this happening? Is this a Next.js issue rather than a Webpack issue? And ultimately, how can I get around this?

**Attempts**

- ```
  import { GLTFLoader } from 'three-full'; // material.customProgramCacheKey is not a function
  ```
- ```
  import { GLTFLoader } from 'three'; TypeError: three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.GLTFLoader is not a constructor
  ```
- ```
  new THREE.GLTFLoader(); TypeError: three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.GLTFLoader is not a constructor
  ```
- ```
  import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'; // Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default. You may need an additional plugin to handle "https:" URIs.
  ```
- package.json `{ "type": "module }`
- etc etc

**next.config.js** *This seems appropriate as something may need to be added here*

```
module.exports = {
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  },
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.module.rules.push(
      // ...

      // Shaders
      {
        test: /\.(glsl|vs|fs|vert|frag)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['raw-loader'],
      }
    );
    return config;
  },
};
```

** EDIT **

I think I found a workaround
https://onion2k.hashnode.dev/loading-a-gltf-model-in-react-three-fiber

** TEMPORARY SOLUTION **

```
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'

const assetURL = "/asset/scene.gltf";
const Asset = useGLTF(assetURL);

scene.add(Asset.scene)

useGLTF.preload(assetURL);
```

Comment: Does this help answer the question: [NextJS + react-hook-mousetrap : “Cannot use import statement outside a module”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66246141/1870780)? Different lib but same solution using `next-transpile-modules`.

Comment: @juliomalves Good find. That didn't work for me out of the box but I'm willing to bet that transpiling is what I'll ultimately have to do. I'll report back when I get more time to check that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `next/dynamic`

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

...

const DynamicPackage = dynamic(() => import('package'), { ssr: false });
```