# How can I use emailjs with NextJS correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to use emailjs in my NextJS application to which you can find the repo [here](https://github.com/jevoncochran/Farms2Communities/tree/development/client). When I deploy the application to Vercel, it throws an error saying I cannot use an import statement outside a module and seems to point to the emailjs import as the source of the error.

[image]

I went ahead and did a dynamic import of emailjs like this:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const emailjs = dynamic(
  () => import("emailjs-com").then((component) => component.emailjs),
  { ssr: false }
);
```

With the dynamic import like this, I am able to deploy to Vercel w/o errors. However, my emailjs code does not work anymore and throws an error that says "emailjs.sendForm is not a function" when the relevant code gets executed. How can I use emailjs with NextJS properly?

Comment: This isn't related specifically to NextJs but to the nature of emailJs package which is presumably not an es6 module. You'll have to use `require("emailjs")` instead of `import`

Comment: I'm confused though because it was working just fine when I used import. The problem only surfaced when I try to deploy the app on Vercel. Why would I be able to use import in development and have to use require on prod?

Comment: That didn't work. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You could always transpile the package, if needed. next-transpile-packages on NPM

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJS + react-hook-mousetrap : "Cannot use import statement outside a module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244968/nextjs-react-hook-mousetrap-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)