# Trying to convert react application to next application

Tags: next.js

Keep getting error

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
cyberoni_next\node_modules\three\examples\jsm\lines\LineGeometry.js:2
import { LineSegmentsGeometry } from "../lines/LineSegmentsGeometry.js";
```

In node modules?? really confused.

```
import { LineSegmentsGeometry } from "../lines/LineSegmentsGeometry.js";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [NextJS + react-hook-mousetrap : "Cannot use import statement outside a module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244968/nextjs-react-hook-mousetrap-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)? Different library but same solution.