# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in nextjs

Tags: next.js

I'm using "react-d3-speedometer" library but getting the above error while importing. can anyone help with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJS + react-hook-mousetrap : "Cannot use import statement outside a module" - Dynamic imports of hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244968/nextjs-react-hook-mousetrap-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Answer (score 4):

This is because NextJS tries to do the server-side rendering and they are components that depend on the browser.

you can fix this by using dynamic import disabling server-side rendering:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const ReactSpeedometer = dynamic(import ("react-d3-speedometer"), { ssr: false })
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I had to make a slight adjustment to get it working for me:

`...  dynamic(() => import ("react-d3-speedometer" ...`