# How to solve SyntaxError: Cannot use import implementing Magic with NextJS in a Typescript setup?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, babeljs

Trying to implement Magic in NextJS using TypeScript.

Following this example/tutorial, which uses JS not TS: https://github.com/magiclabs/example-nextjs

Problem: when importing Magic like so

```
import { Magic } from "magic-sdk";

function createMagic() {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") return null;
  return new Magic(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAGIC_PUBLISHABLE_KEY!);
}

export const magic = createMagic();
```

the following error occurs:

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJS + react-hook-mousetrap : "Cannot use import statement outside a module" - Dynamic imports of hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244968/nextjs-react-hook-mousetrap-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Comment: it does, but posted this in case people are stuck on magic specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Magic uses ESM style modules.

Solved using:

`yarn add next-transpile-modules`

and modifying my `next.config.js` to:

```
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")([
  "magic-sdk",
  "@magic-sdk/provider",
  "@magic-sdk/types",
  "@magic-sdk/commons",
]);

module.exports = withTM({
  reactStrictMode: true,
});
```