# import a file in project root from node_modules

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, next.js, node-modules

Im developing a package from [NextJs](https://nextjs.org/) framework. This package has a middleware handler for API endpoints. So choosing which middlewares to be executed needs to be determined by developer outside the package. For this, I've created a config `.ts` file. The content of file is shown bellow

```js
import withSetCookie from "ngn/middlewares/withSetCookie";
import decryptCookies from "ngn/middlewares/decryptCookies";
import Keyable from "ngn/types/Keyable";
import {Middleware} from "ngn/types/Middleware";
import withRequest from "ngn/middlewares/withRequest";
import withValidator from "ngn/middlewares/withValidator";
import withIp from "ngn/middlewares/withIp";
import withThrottle from "ngn/middlewares/withThrottle";


const middlewares: Keyable<Array<Middleware>> = {
    "/": [
        withRequest,
        withIp,
        withThrottle,
        decryptCookies,
        withSetCookie,
        withValidator
    ]
};

export default middlewares;
```

The problem is I cannot access this file from my package. Is there any way to compile this file and all of its imports into a single commonJs file using webpack? Or is there any way to require this file in my package which located at `node_modules`?

*Note:* It's possible for developer to add his / her own developed middleware to this file. So I cannot get middleware names from user and require middleware files by their names in package.

*Note:* requiring this file directly using both absolute and relative path throws an error which says "Cannot import a module outside a module". And error is referred to middleware imports (E.g: `import withSetCookie from "ngn/middlewares/withSetCookie"`)

*Note:* I've developed an API handler in my package. So I don't want user to install another package like `next-connect` to handle middlewares.

Comment: Have you tried [transpiling your package with `next-transpile-modules`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66246141/1870780) so it can be used in Next.js?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I haven't heard about this package. So I did a minor google search to find out what it is. As I've found out, next-transpile-modules made compiling a node_module package beside project sources possible. So you can simply access that package on dev and production envs. What I want is to compile a file from root directory in a way that I can read it in my package. Can I do something like this with next-transpile-modules?