# Cannot import outside the module

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, next.js, node-modules

Recently I've developed a react package that can be downloaded from npm with the following command

```
npm i react-secuuth
```

which has dependency package which can be downloaded from npm with the command

```
npm i secuuth-sdk-core
```

Whenever I try to use react-secuuth package in my next js application I get an error saying

```
import { getProfile, renewTokens } from "./API";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (K:\SecAuth\core\FrontEnd\node_modules\react-secuuth\dist\index.js:5:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
```

But this package works fine with React applications.

To reproduce:

- Create a nextjs project and install react-secuuth package and import it as shown below

```
import Secuuth from 'react-secuuth';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJS + react-hook-mousetrap : "Cannot use import statement outside a module" - Dynamic imports of hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244968/nextjs-react-hook-mousetrap-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Comment: No it doesn't answer