# How to implement Tawk.to widget in a Next.JS website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have tried what is written on their [@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react) plugin docs?

I have made a component like `/components/Chat.js`

```js
import TawkMessengerReact from "@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react";

export default function Chat() {
  return (
    <div className="chat">
      <TawkMessengerReact
        propertyId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TWAKTO_PROPERTY_ID}
        widgetId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TWAKTO_WIDGET_ID}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

But after importing the component on `Layout.js` or in `_app.js` it's giving an error like

```bash
E:\PROJECT\FOLDER\node_modules\@tawk.to\tawk-messenger-react\src\index.js:4
import { forwardRef, useEffect, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react (E:\PROJECT\FOLDER\.next\server\pages\_app.js:240:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\PROJECT\FOLDER\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
```

What should I do to get it functioning properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question: ["Cannot use import statement outside a module" error when importing react-hook-mousetrap in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66246141/1870780)?

Answer (score 10):

To use the chat widget of Tawk.to I used the Script component with the lazyOnload strategy. You can read more in the [docs.](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script)

```js
import Script from 'next/script';

// inside the return statement of your page
return (
  <>
    <Script
      strategy="lazyOnload"
      src="https://embed.tawk.to/PROPERTY_ID"
    />
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 4):

I was using Next Js and typescript. Since I could not find the types for `tawk-messenger-react` Typescript was failing showing an error and on building, it could `not build` the project. I opted to find a work around by using the `Next Head` and a normal script tag as below.

```
import Head from 'next/head'

<Head>
    <script src="https://embed.tawk.to/PROPERTYID/WIDGETID" async />
</Head>
```

The script will look like:

```
<script src="https://embed.tawk.to/619959c96885f60a50bcbe1e/1fkvgdfr8" async />
```

`Next Script` was not working either for my use case, the widget was `not loading`

Comment: To add on, `next script` with the link to the tawk to element will not work in `next head` but if you place it in the app file just outside the Head component it will work

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for my project:
**npm**:

```
npm i @tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react
```

**yarn**:

```
yarn add @tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react
```

Then add the following:

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Message from "../components/Message";
import Head from "next/head";
import Script from "next/script";
import TawkMessengerReact from "@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react";
import { useRef } from 'react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const tawkMessengerRef = useRef();

  const handleMinimize = () => {
    tawkMessengerRef.current.minimize();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <button onClick={handleMinimize}> Minimize the Chat </button>

      <TawkMessengerReact
        propertyId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TWAKTO_PROPERTY_ID}
        widgetId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TWAKTO_WIDGET_ID}
        useRef={tawkMessengerRef}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

To get more of an idea check out [tawk.to](https://github.com/tawk/tawk-messenger-react/blob/HEAD/docs/how-to-use.md)
for more customization visit [this page](https://github.com/tawk/tawk-messenger-react/blob/HEAD/docs/api-reference.md)

Comment: Important disclaimer, this does not work with Typescript

Comment: yarn add '@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react'

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i have encountered a similar issue, this happens because tawk.to is not meant to be executed on the server. Cannot say the solution is the most elegant, but as a workaround i did a dynamic import of the `TawkMessengerReact` component. And only render it when the app is loaded in the browser. Again, i am sure there might be some more beautiful way to do it, but hey, it is a working quick-and-dirty solution.

```js
const TawkMessengerReact = dynamic(() =>
  import('node_modules/@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react'),
);

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
const initialRenderRef = useRef(false);

 useEffect(() => {
    initialRenderRef.current = true;
  }, []);

return (
<div>
    {initialRenderRef.current && (
     <TawkMessengerReact
      propertyId='asdfasdasdadwswdadw'
      widgetId='asdwer'
     />)}
     <Component {...pageProps} />
</div>


}
```

Comment: dynamic import is the right use case but you need to specify { ssr: false } as a second param to dynamic() .