# ReactJS/NextJS - npm run build fails - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

When running "npm run build" I'm getting the following error:

```
> Build error occurred
C:\Users\...\project\nextjs-frontend\node_modules\mui-rte\index.js:1
export {default} from './dist/MUIRichTextEditor'
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

node_modules/mui-rte/index.js just contains

```
export {default} from './dist/MUIRichTextEditor'
```

However with npm run build my project works just fine and I can use MUIRichTextEditor.

[image]

```
<MUIRichTextEditor
                label="Type something here..."
                onSave={save}
                onChange={handleEditorChange}
                defaultValue={defaultDescValue}
                inlineToolbar={false}
                controls={[
                  "title",
                  "bold",
                  "italic",
                  "underline",
                  "numberList",
                  "bulletList",
                  "quote",
                ]}
              />
```

The build error is preventing me from updating the production version. Does anyone know why I'm getting the export error?

Comment: You most likely need to transpile `mui-rte` library. See ["Cannot use import statement outside a module" error when importing react-hook-mousetrap in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244968/cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-error-when-importing-react-hook-m).

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks, but how do I update the node_modules on Vercel?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, you don't need to update `node_modules` anywhere, you have to transpile `mui-rte` in `next.config.js`.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks so much, now it works. You can create an answer if you want so I can resolve this question.